# What IDE for Spring Framework web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, netbeans, ide

in our company we are switching to Java. We want to develop Web Applications using the Spring Framework. We had 4 days of training where the trainer showed us Java using the Springsource Tool Suite which is based on Eclipse. 
However i have used previously NetBeans for developing PHP applications.

What do i lose using NetBeans 7.0 compared to using Springsource Tool Suite 2.7.0? Is it really worth developing Spring Framework Web Applications using the *dedicated* Springsource Tool Suite with having in mind that we are novice in Java?

**UPDATE**
To provide more information: we want to use the following technologies: 
 - Spring Framework 3
 - JPA (Hibernate)
 - Apache Wicket
 - Maven

Comment: @rationalSpring: Your first paragraph is for me useful, because it's an IDE function. This is a hard argument. The rest is soft (lighweighting, tutorials, freeware).

Answer (score 10):

STS has built in Spring refactoring facility - one among a variety of reasons why STS is the preferred choice for spring development. So for example, you were changing the bean names, the STS will automatically update the bean definition XML files.

I personally prefer eclipse over Intellij Idea; since eclipse is more lightweight than IDEA. Since STS is built on top of eclipse, that makes STS my preference too.

All the spring tutorials and examples by springsource are in STS.

STS is free whereas IDEA is not. I haven't used Netbeans though.

Comment: Can you please update your answer by adding the remaining _reasons why STS is the preferred choice for spring development_ I need a few  more than one argument.

Comment: "STS is the preferred choice for spring development" - preferred by whom? citation needed.

Comment: But STS has some problems comes from eclipse such poor jsp development, slow maven development ,hotdeploy problems not managing by editor  and performance problem such jpa update waiting etc

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend IntelliJ over Eclipse.  I can't speak for STS, since I've never used it, but IntelliJ's Spring support is excellent.

I couldn't disagree more with the comment above stating that Eclipse is lightweight.

Comment: I couldn't agree more about your disagreement.

Answer (score 3):

STS is the best IDE for Spring IMO. Besides Spring ,it includes Maven, Spring Roo which I like very much and there is a version that includes Google's App Engine SDK and GWT SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest reason to go with STS is that the majority of developers using spring choose that IDE.  Most of the tutorials, forum posts and documentation you view will be based on STS.  I also like how maven and tomcat are prepackaged in the IDE.  Also the Spring Template Projects easily port into STS, these projects are extremely helpful because they are prewired.  I'm not sure if you can get them through netbeans without a bunch of initial configuration of maven.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using IntelliJ IDEA. It is the best IDE for developing SpringSource applications in my opinion. You can demo the ultimate version it or use the Community edition.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use IntelliJ IDEA. It has some advanced code related suggestion which would give not only benefit for Spring Framework, but also other frameworks. To me, it is the complete IDE. For Spring it gives convenient auto detection feature. The code navigation for Spring Framework in IntelliJ IDEA gives uniqueness and convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I like IntelliJ quite a bit.  However, if you are an Eclipse shop, look at SpringSource Tool Suite http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts

There are many helpful tools in STS specifically designed for Spring Developers.  Check out my DZone Refcard which was just published this week http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/eclipse-tools-spring